# Webscraping Stock Data every 5 seconds

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, finance, yahoo

I am trying to scrape the price of a stock off of yahoo finance as it updates every 5 seconds, but I cannot figure out a way to get the most recent stock price. Only the open and close price. I believe my problem is that I am trying to scrape data that is dynamic, changes constantly. Does anyone know a solution for this?

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Which Symbol are you searching
#t_symbol = input("What stock are you searching?")
def getData(t_symbol):
    url = f'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{t_symbol}'+f'?p={t_symbol}&.tsrc=fin-srch'

    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    price = soup.find('fin-streamer', {'class':'Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)'}).get('value')
    print(price)

    #webbrowser.open(url)
    return price

getData('NIO')
```

Comment: You'll have to use a library that supports running JS code; I suggest selenium.

Comment: You want to scrape the ticker data (the big number that constantly changes on the webpage while the market is open) on yahoo finance, not the opening/closing prices under "summary"